# NULL pointer cause "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)"

Tags: c++, valgrind

On a C++ project, Valgrind is telling me that I have a "*Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)*", that I really do not understand.

As the project is too broad and for legal reasons, I can't copy/past the code. And I don't know how to do a little program that reproduces the error, cause I really do not understand it!

So, here is the function causing my troubles. All names have been replaced.

```cpp
Object2* Object1::get_thing(optix::float3 startCoord) {
  Object2* obj=NULL;

  // this->objs is of type Object2*
  if (this->objs!=NULL) { // <- This condition is false when Valgrind complains at the next if, but it never gives a Vagrind error
    obj=this->objs->get_thing(startCoord);
  }
  else {
    obj=NULL; // <- The program goes here
  }

  if (obj==NULL) { // <- Valgrind is complaining here
    /* Do some stuff */
  }

  return obj;
}
```

As you can see, Valgrind gives me the error when I test if `obj` is `NULL`. But I ran the code step by step in GDB (with Valgrind), so I know that `obj` is `NULL`, but when I arrive on the test line, Valgrind complains.

When I set the `--track-origins=yes` option to Valgrind, it tells me that the variable has been allocated on the stack.

I'm not asking anybody to debug my code. I just like to have some ideas of reasons why it can give this error in a simple case like this one.

EDIT:
Valgrind reports only two errors before this one, and they are both in the Cuda library.

Comment: How is `this->objs` initialized?

Comment: This code is not a [mcve], and the bug is in the code not provided.

Comment: In Debug builds, uninitialized variables often have some well-defined value, such as 0. The value you see in the debugger does not prove that the variable is initialized.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It depends :s It can be with a `new`, or by moving (copying the pointer) a previously created object

Comment: @Eljay did you read all my post!?

Comment: @vll If I replace it by `if (false)` my program will crash a way before, because this function is called a lot of time. I understand, but in this case, it has been initialized to `NULL`, no?

Comment: Delete the else part, it is unneeded.

Comment: How confident are you that `Object2::get_thing` doesn't have a bug?

Comment: Yes, I read all your post.  Some ideas where to look is in the code not provided, because the bug is not in the code provided.

Comment: @vll It seems I explained my problem in an unclear way, sorry. I edited my post. There is only one error in this function, `if (obj==NULL)`. `this->objs` never gives any error.

Comment: @Eljay I'm asking for potential reason why it can give this error. I edited my post, hope you will like it better this way

Comment: perhaps `this->objs` is uninitialized

Comment: Add a check for NULL at the return of `get_thing`.

Comment: @vll By "often" do you mean "with Visual Studio"? On platforms supported by Valgrind, I would say "almost never".

Comment: @Surt Removing the else will potentially change the behaviour. If `obj` is non-null and `this->objs` is NULL then the else alters `obj`

Comment: Which version of Valgrind are you using? And which compiler and optimization flags? And which OS? Is the `this` object well formed (try using gdb monitor commands on the memory for `this`, see here https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands)

Comment: @PaulFloyd obj is initialized to NULL already so removing the extra assignment should not change the behavior.

Comment: @Surt Oops you are right. I misread it as a default valued argument.

Comment: In that case also look closely at `get_thing()` to check that it isn't overwriting the stack. Memcheck doesn't detect array bounds violations of stack objects.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Vagrind 3.14.0, gcc 4.8.5 20150623, with flags `-O0` and `-g3`. And I'm under CentOS 7. I'll have a look to the monitor commands. And `get_thing()` Is very simylar. It has also one stack variable (returned) which is a pointer initialized almost the same way